# Checkout session malformation (Stripe API)

Tags: stripe-payments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrx7W.png)

This is what i am seeing, sends me to URl but the content will not load, any thoughts?

I am trying to look through the docs

Comment: Can you share details on how you're creating and redirecting to the Checkout Session?

Comment: I am creating the URL from a post-checkout session call, then I am using the external link from that to send the user however the link changes by a few characters when I I use it as an external link .

Comment: Can you share the **exact** code you're using between the response from your Checkout Session create call and the redirect? It sounds like something is malforming the URL.